# Incompatible nullness constraints in java class hierarchy with generics

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, eclipse-jdt, type-annotation

I am in the middle of migrating my java codebase for a project from java7 to java8. In the process I am also switching from the javax.annotation @Nullable, @NonNull and @ParametersAreNotNullByDefault annotations to the org.eclipse.jdt annotations for null-analysis in eclipse (Mars Release 4.5.0:Build id: 20150621-1200). 
In doing this, I stumbled upon a situation where I can't compile (because of strict eclipse settings with regard to annotation based null checking) because of something I can't explain. I am not looking to find a way to compile my code, but more to understand why the error is occurring.

I have the following classes in a package specifying default non nullness using `@NonNullByDefault` in a `package-info.java`.

I have an interface implemented by an abstract class which is in turn extended by a concrete class as follows:

```
public interface SimulationComponent {

    <T extends SimulationComponent> List<T> getCorrectSimulationSubComponents();

    List<? extends SimulationComponent> getErroneousSimulationSubComponents();
}


public abstract class AbstractSimulationComponent
        implements SimulationComponent {

    @Override
    public List<SimulationComponent> getCorrectSimulationSubComponents() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<SimulationComponent> getErroneousSimulationSubComponents() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}

public class ConcreteSubSimComponent extends AbstractSimulationComponent {
    public void doSomething() {
    }
}
```

Eclipse notifies me of the following problem in ConcreteSubSimComponent:

```
The method @NonNull List<@NonNull SimulationComponent> getErroneousSimulationSubComponents() from 
 AbstractSimulationComponent cannot implement the corresponding method from SimulationComponent due 
 to incompatible nullness constraints
```

This problem seems to be caused by the generics wildcard in `getErroneousSimulationSubComponents()`. This is how I specified the method that resulted in me noticing the problem when migrating to java8. 
I figured out that I could 'easily' fix things by just replacing this method signature to the one shown in `getCorrectSimulationSubComponents()`.
I don't see why this last version works and the previous version doesn't.

Also, this only seems to be a problem in the concrete subclass. A concrete class directly implementing the interface does not show any problems.

I am using JavaSE-1.8 and an example project with the code that does not compile, can be found at https://github.com/KrisC369/NullProblemIllustration

Comment: Did you try with a more recent build of eclipse? If it is because of a bug in the eclipse compiler, it could be fixed already. I'm aware of a number of null analysis related bugs fixed in neon as well as mars.2. Take a look at the bugs tagged [null] filed against jdt core in eclipse bugzilla. If you cannot find one that fits your problem, do file a bug

Comment: It seems that the mars.1 build still has the bug while I can't reproduce it in mars.2rc2 and neon-M4 build.
Over the weekend a bug report [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=485988) has been submitted that seems to fit the behaviour I'm experiencing as well but it is submitted under version 4.6.0 of JDT-Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly, this bug has been resolved by the changes introduced to fix bug [436091](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=436091) against JDT-core. 
This fix should be present in eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2) and eclipse neon-M4 (4.6.0-M4).